# Tabs with dropdowns angular ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I am trying to create an application with Angularjs, angular ui and bootstrap 3. I need to create new tabs on the fly by adding object to the array.

```
<div ng-controller="PersonCtrl">
    <button ng-click="AddPerson()">Add Person</button>
    <button ng-click="RemovePerson()">Remove Person</button>
    <tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="p in Persons" heading="{{[p.Name}}">
    </div>
    </tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
```

Instead of buttons to add and remove I want to add a Dropdown tab to the end. See the plunk...
http://plnkr.co/edit/GtuG3UCS2WZvEZpoSiAj?p=preview

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking?  What items will be in the dropdown?  Where should the dropdown be visible?  What will trigger the adding of a new tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/hA0vFlKW2W2yTsV147yk?p=preview) example in plunker. May be it will help you.

```
<div class="bs-example">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li ng-repeat="p in Persons"><a href="#">{{p.Name}}</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Action <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a ng-click="AddPerson()" href="#">Add person</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="RemovePerson()" href="#">Remove person</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Got it working.. Thanks... But what you are suggesting seems to be plain Bootstrap... is there a way to do the same using Angular UI ?

Comment: I would like an angular ui example too.